# GraphDB queries fail silently (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I'm dealing with a pretty huge repository (i.e., ~16M statements). I'm trying to get a list of all distinct class membership patterns in my graph. Here is the query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select distinct (group_concat(?t) as ?fo)
where { 
    ?s rdf:type ?t.    
} 

group by (?s)
order by ?fo
```

Of course such a query does have to return results. Strangely enough, sometimes I get the result that I need, sometimes the query returns no results.

Why is that happening and how can I avoid that?

PS:
Monitoring the query, I noticed that when I have no data, the query status stays stuck on:

```
IN_HAS_NEXT

0 operations
```

until the conclusion.

**Update:**

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Mp1xd9hG) is the main log describing the problem. The output in the workbench of GraphDB is:

> No results. Query took 1m 53s, minutes ago.

No mention of errors. Quite strange. As Gilles-Antoine Nys pointed out, it is a problem with memory and Java's GC. Overall, I think that the workbench should explicitly show an error message in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other comments already have suggested the error is caused by OME. In the next upcoming GraphDB 8.6 release, the developers made a much more memory efficient implementation of all aggregates and distinct. Until its public release, there are only few options to test:

1. Decrease the amount of consumed memory by writing a slightly more optimal version of your query, which displays only the local names:

> ```
> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
> select ?s_local (group_concat(?t_local) as ?fo)
> where {
>     ?s rdf:type ?t.
>     BIND (REPLACE(STR(?t), "^(.*)(/|#)([^#/]*)$", "$3") as ?t_local)
>     BIND (REPLACE(STR(?s), "^(.*)(/|#)([^#/]*)$", "$3") as ?s_local)
> } group by (?s_local)
> order by (?fo)
> ```

2. Increase the available RAM for performing all aggregate calculations. You can increase it by either passing a higher value of the `-Xmx` parameter or setting a minimal number for `graphdb.page.cache.size` in graphdb.properties like: `graphdb.page.cache.size=100M`. The cache controls the number of stored in memory pages, which for your query and repository size won't make much of a difference.
3. Limit the the maximum length of the group concat string with `-Dgraphdb.engine.function.concat.max-length=4096`. The limit won't make the query to execute successfully, but it will indicate, whether the problem is too many subjects too long strings.

Answer (score 3):

First, your query is not able to give you the class that can be defined by the types... I recommenced to add `?s` in your `select` for expressivness. So you can easily answer your question.

Here is the simpliest query for it :

```
select ?s (group_concat(?t) as ?fo)
where { 
?s rdf:type ?t.    
} group by (?s)
```

( `order by(?fo)` can be added if it is important for you ).

Secondly, the `IN_HAS_NEXT` is just a state of the query when you pause it in the monitor. Nothing to do with an error.

And finally, verify your `query-timeout` parameter. Its default value is set to 0.

**Update :**

Actually you have two errors in your LogFile. The problem is that your JVM is taking too long to Garbage Collector your memory (more than 98% of your memory is still used).

One solution is to increase your GC overhead limit and therefore allows to deal with your huge dataset.

Comment: Hello. I do not understand your caveat about the query. I was looking for a list of all distinct class membership patterns (maybe I have to specify it better in my question). Anyway, I did not pause the query, it seems like GraphDB encountered some execution problems and they are not systematic. PS:`query-timeout` is already set to 0.

Comment: Have you already read the Logs? (..\AppData\Roaming\GraphDB\logs)

Comment: Log inserted in the original post.

Comment: Got it! Do you know an effective way to deal with that in GraphDB?

Comment: PS: I tried to launch GraphDB with option `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` but I did not solve (and it's not recommended).

Comment: Indeed `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` is hard solution. Perhaps can you try on a machine with more RAM? Don't know if it can improve the processing but in a more "natural" way.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it seems there is no solution (I'm working with 16GB of RAM)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with GraphDB Free is: It increases heap size as per the workbench is called. For example, if you query or just refresh the workbench you could see the Heap size increases. Now even you do have large amount of memory, querying successively larger number of query shall produce OOM as the heap size is increasing continuously. The solution might be to look for temporary data stored by GraphDB on every call which increases the heap size.